# Passing in a class variable to the base class constructor C++

Tags: c++, constructor, abstraction

I have an implementation of a base class which constructs some array of a size that is known at runtime. When I call the constructor of the base class, I would like to pass in a reference to one of the values in this array. The following example code illustrates this (my actual code includes error handling that is not relevant here).

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    public:
        int & someInteger;

        Base(int & thisIsSomeInteger) : someInteger(thisIsSomeInteger) {}

};

class Impl : public Base {
    public:
        int * someArray;

        Impl(int size) : 
            someArray(new int[size]),
            Base(someArray[2])
        {}
};

int main()
{
    Impl test(5);

    test.someArray[2] = 20;

    // Not the same!
    std::cout << &test.someInteger << "\n";
    std::cout << &test.someArray[2] << "\n";
}
```

**Desired behaviour**

Both `&test.someInteger` and `&test.someArray[2]` point to the same address in memory.

**Actual behaviour**

`&test.someInteger` and `&test.someArray[2]` point to different addresses in memory. I expect that this is the case because the base class constructor is called first in the initialization list, meaning that `someArray` hasn't been allocated yet when the base constructor is called.

**Possible work around**

Initalize `someInteger` to an address and then change `someArray[2]` to point to this address instead of whatever address it was allocated to. However, this feels very clunky to me and seems like bad practice.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is main problem of Object Oriented Programing? It is misunderstood and inheritance is overused. Please describe functionality of `Base` so we can disparage you from inheriting it.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.  The compiler ought to warn you that your initializers are out of order.  The `Base` initializer happens **before** the `someArray` initializer, but the code as written misleadingly *appears* that it's the other way around.

Comment: Best solution is probably to replace `int &someInteger` by a virtual function `virtual int &GetSomeInteger() = 0`. Alternatively, using a pointer in the base class might also works. Another trick would be to keep the array and size in the base class. In practice, solution could depend othe other derived classes... If `Impl` is the only derived class, then someArray should be in the base class... **Why you want it that way?**

Answer (score 2):

> this is the case because the base class constructor is called first in the initialization list

Yes, it is. You can use multiple subclasses to control initialization order.

```
class Base {
    public:
        int & someInteger;

        Base(int & thisIsSomeInteger) : someInteger(thisIsSomeInteger) {}

};

class ArrayBase {

public:

        int * someArray;
        ArrayBase(int size) : 
            someArray(new int[size]) {}
};

class Impl : public ArrayBase, public Base {
    public:

        Impl(int size) : ArrayBase(size),
            Base(someArray[2])
        {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use constructor chaining introducing a private `Impl::Impl(int[])` that gets the array as parameter allowing you to determine the reference to pass on to the base class constructor based on the first parameter:

```
class Impl : public Base {
public:
    int* someArray;

    Impl(int size)
        : Impl(new int[size])
    {
    }

private:
    Impl(int arr[])
        : Base(arr[2]),
        someArray(arr)
    {
    }
};
```

**Note:** If you implement destructor logic to free the memory, you need to be extra careful to not access `Base::someInteger` in `Base::~Base()`, since `Impl::~Impl()` executes the base class destructor at its very end after everything `Impl`-related has been freed.

Also there are potential issues with freeing the array, if `Base::Base(int&)` can throw and exception; It would be preferrabe to have an object such as `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` or `std::vector<int>` owning the array to ensure the memory is freed, if an error happens.

Comment: With that solution, Base constructor should be `nothrow`

Comment: @Phil1970 You mean `noexcept`? Note that I've only mentioned possible issues with exceptions, since the question doesn't seem to be concerned about properly releasing resources. Making the constructor parameter of the private constructor and the type of the member variable type a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` and moving to the member in the constructor would result in the memory being released properly.

Comment: Yes, I mean `noexcept` or more precisely that the constructor should not throw to ensure no memory leak (in case of an exception if one care about it)

Comment: One could also use a `vector` ([like this](https://godbolt.org/z/W9Prdb8vv)) to ensure that there are no leaks and to not have to implement the rule of 5 manually.